# Is it possible to store function values in a hash table?

Tags: java, android, mobile

I want to store functions as values in a HashTable for my android device.  Is that possible?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? It may be possible, but there is probably an easier way to do what you want. What is it that you need to do?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! If you a response is helpful, pleas up vote it. If the response successfully answers you question please click the green check mark next to it to accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do that using what's called [Reflection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/). You'd create some sort of HashTable, like this:

```
HashTable<String, Method> functionsMap = new HashTable<String, Method>;
```

Here's more information on the [Method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html) class.

That said, reflection is generally a bad idea. When ever you feel the need to use Reflection, you should ask yourself, "Do I really need to do things this way? Is there some way I can accomplish what I'm trying to do with out reflection?". If after thinking very hard for several minutes the answer to your question is still "Yep, I need reflection", then go ahead and use it.

Comment: @Gray That's why I added the blurb about not using reflection. Just because he's a newbie doesn't mean he shouldn't know what's out there. I disagree with your assesment.

Answer (score 0):

No, java doesn't allow that.  What you could do is create some sort of interface that allows you to provide custom implementations of a specific method.

For instance

```
public interface CustomerHandler{
  public void handle();
}
```

And then you could create custom implementations of this interface and add those objects to a hashmap.  Then you could retrieve the objects and call the method.

```
HashMap<String, CustomHandler> map = new HashMap<String, CustomHandler>();
//add objects
map.get("some_handler").handle();
```

Comment: I disagree @Will.  Chris' solution is certainly a much more elegant solution to the problem then a reflection hack.

Comment: @Gray Chris said it could not be done, it can. That was my main point. I do agree this might be a better way, though.

Comment: @Will, you're right, my bad.  I was thinking about it the way you might in C or C++, but you are correct, it can be done via reflection.

Comment: I agree @Will.  I objected too strongly to the reflection answer.  Although technically right it is just a terrible solution to this guy's obviously naive question.  But it is correct.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From Java7 on, you can create MethodHandles to represent functions (methods).
And of course, you can store 'em anywhere, including Hashtables.